# Using IO with Ncurses

Tags: haskell, io, ncurses

I am trying to use UI.NCurses

https://john-millikin.com/software/haskell-ncurses/reference/haskell-ncurses/latest/

for some simple path finding lessons
The issue is I have a random Int which of course returns an IO Int
which then means I have an IO TerrianType which then leads to an array of IO TerrianType

the issue is I need to resolve these in main so they can be printed to the screen using drawString. I am including the code below:

```
module Main where
  2   import UI.NCurses
  3   import Control.Monad
  4   import Control.Monad.IO.Class
  5   import System.Random
  6 
  7   -- Tutorials
  8   -- working on several path findng algorithims
  9   -- http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html
 10 
 11   -- | The 'Compass' data type provides breadcrumbs from the goal to the start. 
 12   data Compass = N | S | E | W deriving (Show, Eq)
 13 
 14   -- | 'Cartogram' is a structure of compass directions that mirrors the terrian.
 15   type Cartogram = [Compass]
 16 
 17   -- | 'TerrianType' determines how hard a cell is to traverse.
 18   data TerrianType = Sand | Forest | Goal deriving (Show, Eq)
 19 
 20   -- | 'Terrian' is a collection of TerrianTypes with a single goal.
 21   type Terrian = [IO TerrianType]
 22 
 23   -- | 'roll' gets a random int from 1 to the parameter
 24   roll :: Int -> IO Int
 25   roll m
 26     | m <= 0 = getStdRandom (randomR (1,1))
 27     | m > 0 = getStdRandom (randomR (1,m)) 
 28 
 29   -- | 'getRandomTerrian' gets a random TerrianType 
 30   getRandomTerrian :: IO TerrianType
 31   getRandomTerrian = do
 32     r <- roll 3
 33     case r of
 34       1 -> return Forest
 35       2 -> return Sand
 36       3 -> return Goal
 37       _ -> return Sand
 38 
 39   -- | 'constructTerrian' constructs a Terrian array of random TerrianTypes
 40   constructTerrian :: Int -> Int -> Terrian
 41   constructTerrian n1 n2 = take (n1 * n2) $ repeat getRandomTerrian
 42 
 43   drawShow a = (drawString . show) a
 44  
 45   --showString :: t -> String
 46   --showString t = show t
 47 
 48   main :: IO ()
 49   main = do
 50     runCurses $ do
 51       setEcho False
 52       w <- defaultWindow
 53       updateWindow w $ do
 54         moveCursor 1 1
 55         mapM drawShow (constructTerrian 5 5)
 56       render
 57       waitFor w (\ev -> ev == EventCharacter 'q' || ev == EventCharacter 'Q')58 
 59   waitFor :: Window -> (Event -> Bool) -> Curses ()
 60   waitFor w p = loop where
 61     loop = do
 62       ev <- getEvent w Nothing
 63       case ev of
 64         Nothing -> loop
 65         Just ev' -> if p ev' then return () else loop

 • No instance for (Show (IO TerrianType))
        arising from a use of ‘drawShow’
 • In the first argument of ‘mapM’, namely ‘drawShow’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: mapM drawShow (constructTerrian 5 5)
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘do { moveCursor 1 1;
              mapM drawShow (constructTerrian 5 5) }’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing `[IO TerrianType]` and `IO [TerrianType]`.

In your code you produce a `[IO TerrianType]`, which is a list of IO actions. When you `mapM` over that, you have to *run* the actions if you want to access their `TerrianType` and print it.

So, you probably need something like

```
drawShow :: (IO TerrianType) -> IO ()
drawShow a = a >>= drawString . show
```

However, I do wonder if `[IO TerrianType]` is the right thing to begin with. Instead of using

```
constructTerrian :: Int -> Int -> [IO TerrianType]
```

as you are doing now, you probably should move to

```
constructTerrian :: Int -> Int -> IO [TerrianType]
```

and change the code accordingly. The first code does not compute the random values, but only returns a list of IO actions which will roll the random values. Maybe you instead want to roll them now, and produce a list of values, as the second type implies.

Comment: hey thaks I will give that a shot. not sure if I can do IO [TerrianType] becasue the IO comes from the random Int but will try

Comment: Yeah: Couldn't match expected type ‘IO Terrian’
                  with actual type ‘[IO TerrianType]’
    • In the expression: take (n1 * n2) $ repeat getRandomTerrian

Comment: @liminal18 Note that we have `sequence :: [IO a] -> IO [a]` which can convert one into the other. Probably there are better ways to do it, but this is a basic way, at least.

Comment: Yeah I ended up using replicateM on the random function to compile a list of int then constructing my TerrainType list. Is working thanks